# Check if the device is sending an HDMI signal

Tags: java, android, hdmi

I'm building an Android app at my work, and one of the features has to be that the app can detect if it is connected to a *monitor* and sending signal with HDMI. I've found a script that checks if the HDMI port is connected, but when the *monitor* is off, it still gives me true because the *HDMI circuit* is still connected.

I want to see true if the device is sending a signal an when the *monitor* is on, and false if the *monitor* is off or if the device can't send a signal to the *monitor*.

Comment: Just as a heads up, I've had monitors accepting an HDMI signal even though they're completely turned off. So whatever solution you will come to, it might not be perfect for every case.